# How to add resource in web.php laravel 7?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with the `Route::resource()` method in Laravel 7.x. The error it returns is:

> Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UserController] does not exist.

[image: error]

Here is my code in routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::namespace('Admin')->prefix('admin')->middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
    Route::resource('/users', App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UserController::class);
});
```

I could not find where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel 7, the namespace for controllers are already set in the `RouteServiceProvider`. So when you are again using the full namespace for the controllers using `Route::resource('/users', App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UserController::class);`, you are actually saying to look for your controller into `App\Http\Controllers\Admin\App\Http\Controllers\Admin` folder which does not exist and hence the error. This is not related to the resource route.
just use

```
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
```

> used `user` as singular form to maintain the standard naming convention

Comment: I see this error again ` Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UserController::class] does not exist. `

Comment: Why use this code `Route::resource('user', 'UserController');` in new version karavel?

Comment: sorry, didn't get your question. by new version, you mean laravel 8?